# How Vaiṣṇavas resolve the paradox regarding belief in the transcendental world where a devotee comes after his death?

Tags: philosophy, vaishnavism

If Vaikuntha or Goloka is transcendental to material time, space, the entire material world, then how can we apply the law of causality to these spiritual world? Because if we say that our behavior in this world will affect whether we return (or just go) to the spiritual world or not, it means that the state of affairs in the spiritual world is causally dependent on events here.

Which implies that the spiritual world is somehow dependent on this material world, and therefore it is just another material world. However, if it is transcendental to the gunas, karmas, etc., then our being in it cannot be affected by our behavior and actions here. Or is everything completely different. I don't accept the argument that this is beyond logic. Because outside logic does not mean contradicting logic.

Is this something that the Vaishnavas have ever dealt with in the history of Vaishnava theology and philosophy?